What are these Ports on Multimeter PCB & What Protocol are they Using?
I have disassembled the AstroAI DM200M, a cheap multimeter, and am trying to read data from the jumper ports connected to the PCB. Using an oscilloscope, it seems the serial ports are not actually sending any real data, but wanted to confirm. What is this pin-out used for and what communication protocol (if any) are they using?
On the PCB, with traces to a cobbed chip, are 7 ports labeled "J1" (I will reference these ports left to right)



Port
Commentary




1
Has continuity with the "BAT -" on the PCB, so I think this is ground


2
Has constant DC voltage ~4.26V


3
Has constant DC voltage ~3.32V; may be reference voltage


4
Seems to be a serial signal


5
Same as #4, but offset one pulse


6
Same as #5, but offset one pulse


7
Same as #6, but offset one pulse



Photo of the Exposed PCB & Relevant Ports

Scope Screenshot of Ports 1, 2, 3

Scope Screenshot of Port 4 (Labeled 1)

Scope Screenshot of Port 4, 5, 6, 7 (Labeled 1, 2, 3, 4)

I have read the Multimeter documentation (link), but it does not provide any relevant information on these ports.

The first three look like DC signals, as you would expect with such general-purpose pin headers.

They look like LCD driving waveforms. Specifically as there are four of them so they could be the four commons for a matrixed LCD.
It can be a header for product testing and calibration, while simultaneously being a set of vias for the LCD signals going to the other side of PCB and to the display.
Also note that the signals may be the LCD common signals while the chip runs normally, but there is a possibility that these pins are multi-purpose, they might be the firmware programming and calibration interface during manufacture.

It seems unlikely they would be used for testing the LCD output directly, as there's no pins to read the segments on each digit.  But they could be the MCU's programming interface like JTAG or similar (pull a pin high/low at power on time to enable programming mode) and the pins are GPIOs in normal use.  They could also enable a debugging / calibration mode in firmware by having a routine to detect a specific pattern on them when the firmware starts.

Thank you for the replies, I had believed they were JTAG as well, but couldn't understand why the data pins were sending data-like square-waves, but they were all the same. Truthfully, I don't know what TCK, TMS, TDI, or TDO typically look like in a scope. I should note that bridging some of them to the perceived ground (Pin 1) makes it beep sometimes, but doesn't seem to affect anything else.
